# HTML error using functions from bundle.js

Tags: javascript, html, webpack, bundle

I've created a bundle.js file using webpack to organize all my javascript code. I was expecting to use it in my html file but having troubles using the function. An error always returns when I try to call the function  `index.html:9 Uncaught TypeError: App.testButton is not a function at setup`.

I had the impression that if I configured the webpack with the library output specified, I would be able to access the functions via the specified library name.

What am I doing wrong?

**App.js**

```
import testButton from './testButton.js';

console.log("I'm the entry point");
testButton();
```

**testButton.js**

```
function testButton()
{
    console.log("Test Button");
};

export default testButton;
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <script src="dist/bundle.js"></script>
  <script>
  function setup()
    {
        console.log("Initializing a webpage");
        App.testButton()
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body onload="setup();">
</body>
</html>
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './app.js',
  mode: 'development',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    libraryTarget: 'var',
    library: 'App'
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this to work for me. I needed to modify App.js to include babel so I could use ES5 which allowed me to use require to populate module.exports.

**App.js**

```
require('babel-register')({
    presets: ['env']
});

module.exports = {
    testButton: require('./testButton.js'),
    testButton2: require('./testButton2.js')
};
```

**testButton.js**

```
export function testButton()
{
    console.log("Test Button");
};
```

**testButton2.js**

```
export function testButton()
{
    console.log("Test Button 2");
};
```

**index.html**

```
function setup()
{
    App.testButton.testButton();
    App.testButton2.testButton();
}
</script>
```

**Output in Console**
    Test Button
    test Button 2